# convert RGBD image to a polygon mesh

Tags: mesh, data-conversion, point-clouds

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36890562/how-to-generate-a-3d-point-cloud-from-depth-image-and-color-image-acquired-from) on how to convert a depth image into a point cloud. What I need is to convert it into a ply file with triangle and vertices (full triangular mesh).

Is this even possible without any special algorithm?

Comment: I dont think thats possible without a very special algorithm

Comment: Why not make a pair of triangles in each quad? e.g. ((1,1), (1, 2), (2,1)), and ((1,2), (2, 2), (2, 1)), using the depth values that correspond to each (x, y) as the z for each vertex. Repeat until all pixels in the image are meshed.

Comment: I have actually found an answer in [this paper](http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2016/papers/Firman_Structured_Prediction_of_CVPR_2016_paper.pdf) from 2016. It is way more complicated to my need though, so as of now @A.Blub you are correct to say it is not possible (as in, not trivial or a simple operation).